# Facing problem in adding data in mongoDB in my MERN App

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I'm creating a MERN app in which people can add tasks and collab with other persons.

I started my backend by the `nodemon index.js` command in the git bash terminal.
Whenever I'm trying to POST requests for the data. My terminal gives me an error and can't add that data to my MongoDB.

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GOkv.png)

[there is the source code](https://github.com/Aliwahid17/inotebook-MERN.git)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose lets you start using your models immediately, without waiting for mongoose to establish a connection to MongoDB.
That’s because mongoose buffers model function calls internally. This buffering is convenient, but also a common source of confusion. Mongoose will not throw any errors by default if you use a model without connecting.

you could at least set a handler for the error event. basically, it is this:

```
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URL,
  options,
  (err) => {
   if(err) console.log(err) 
   else console.log("mongdb is connected");
  }
);

// or

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URL,
  options
)
.then(()=>console.log('connected'))
.catch(e=>console.log(e));
```

Or using async/try/catch.

Comment: It is still not working :(